# C++ Method Pointer?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly

I’m running on Wintel and I want to be able to call a variable method of any object as long as I know the method signature. Is the following assembler correct? Do I need to save/restore ECX? It seems to work but I want to know if I’m missing something. Yeah, yeah, say goodbye type safety, danger is my middle name...

So, why would I want to do this? I have a message distribution system. Business logic subscribes for messages and the distribution system hands them out when they come in. Right now I’m using an interface definition. I have business objects that need to receive multiple message types. Each handler function has a block of if-else statements to figure out the message type. I would like a single class to subscribe to multiple message types and have different methods for each type. I could switch to function pointers, but then I’d have a bunch of static methods and non-static counter parts.

It’s only 3 assembler instructions, how bad could it be?? *Looks down the slippery slope*

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A {
public:
    A(int i){
        m_i = i;
    }

    void test(int i){
        printf("m_i = %i, i = %i\n",m_i,i);
    }

private:
    int m_i;
};

void callmethod(void *object, const void *function, int i){
    __asm {
        push [i];
        mov ecx, object;
        call function;
    }
}

int main(){
    A a(123);
    callmethod(&a,_ADDRESSOF(A::test),456);
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

> m_i = 123, i = 456

Here's a more detailed example of what I have now and comments explaining what I would like to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <list>

using std::unordered_map;
using std::list;

class IMessage {
};

class MessageHandler {
public:
    virtual ~MessageHandler(){}
    virtual void HandleMessage(int type, IMessage *message) = 0;
};

class MessageDispatcher {
public:

    void Subscribe(int type, MessageHandler *callback){
        m_callbacks[type].push_back(callback);
    }

    void ProcessMessage(int type, IMessage *message){
        if (m_callbacks.find(type) != m_callbacks.end()){
            list<MessageHandler*> &callbacks = m_callbacks[type];
            for (list<MessageHandler*>::iterator i = callbacks.begin(); i != callbacks.end(); ++i){
                (*i)->HandleMessage(type,message);
            }
        }
    }

private:

    unordered_map<int,list<MessageHandler*> > m_callbacks;

};

class BusinesLogic : public MessageHandler {
public:

    BusinesLogic(MessageDispatcher *md){
        md->Subscribe(0,this); // I want to put HandleType0 here like this
                               // md-Subscribe(0,this,HandleType0);
        md->Subscribe(1,this); // I want to put HandleType1 here like this
                               // md-Subscribe(1,this,HandleType1);
    }

private:

    void HandleType0(IMessage *message){
        printf("Got type 0\n");
    }

    void HandleType1(IMessage *message){
        printf("Got type 1\n");
    }

    virtual void HandleMessage(int type, IMessage *message){
        // I want to do away with this switch block and let the MessageDispatcher
        // class call into the HandleType0 and HandleType1 methods directly
        // without using static methods
        switch (type){
        case 0:
            HandleType0(message);
            break;
        case 1:
            HandleType1(message);
            break;
        }
    }
};

int main(){

    MessageDispatcher md;

    BusinesLogic bl(&md);

    md.ProcessMessage(0,nullptr);
    md.ProcessMessage(1,nullptr);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the proper way? `template <class X>
void callmethod(X &object, void (X::*function)(int), int i) {
    (object.*function)(i);
}`

Comment: `cdecl` is caller cleanup, so at the very least you should cleanup the argument you pushed. Normally that's done using `add esp, 4`. You might get away with it if your compiler generates a frame pointer and thus restores the stack for you, but you'd better not depend on that.

Comment: The message distribution code doesn't know anything about the business logic code. There is no way for the message distribution code to know the name of all the business logic classes. Maybe I don't understand how to use the code you suggest. Can you show me an example where callmethod doesn't know the class type?

Comment: @Jester Thanks, yeah, visual studio is adding the boilerplate stack setup and tear-down. I'll add the `add esp, 4` and see if the optimizer removes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use pointers to members like Kay suggested in his first comment.

A simple way do this would be something like the following example:

```
virtual void HandleMessage(int type, IMessage *message){
    typedef void (BusinesLogic::*handler_mfn_type)(IMessage *);
    static const handler_mfn_type dispatch_table[] = {
        &BusinesLogic::HandleType0,
        &BusinesLogic::HandleType1
    };
    handler_mfn_type mfn = dispatch_table[type];
    (this->*mfn)(message);
}
```

No inline assembler and no static functions. No subscribing to the methods themselves either, but I'm not sure if that's a bad thing.

If you really want to be able to pass the method in the Subscribe call then you'll need to wrap it in a class that bundles the (pointer to) method with a pointer to the object. There's no escaping the fact that you need both to invoke a method.

Create a base class and a template like this:

```
class callback_base {
public:
    virtual void call_handler(IMessage *) = 0;
};

template <class T>
class callback: public callback_base {
    typedef void (T::*mfn_type)(IMessage *);

    T *obj;
    mfn_type mfn;

public:
    callback(T *a, mfn_type b): obj(a), mfn(b) {}

    virtual void call_handler(IMessage *msg) {
        (obj->*mfn)(msg);
    }
};
```

And use it like this:

```
md->Subscribe(0,new callback<BusinesLogic>(this, &BusinesLogic::HandleType0));
md->Subscribe(1,new callback<BusinesLogic>(this, &BusinesLogic::HandleType1));
```

```
void Subscribe(int type, callback_base *cb){
    m_callbacks[type].push_back(cb);
}
```

```
void ProcessMessage(int type, IMessage *message){
    ...
        for (list<callback_base *>::iterator i = callbacks.begin(); i != callbacks.end(); ++i){
            (**i).call_handler(message);
        }
```